# Does anyone know the Meaning of " A man is a man for all that.?"

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does it mean? As Robert Burns stated  in poem "A man is a man for all that?"

Comment: ***For all that*** is an idiomatic expression:  in spite of that - 
*he was a nice man for all that* - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-all-that

Comment: The Burns poem is about equality - all men are of equal value regardless of wealth and social status.

Comment: I always thought the line was _A Man’s a man for **a’** that_.

Answer (score 2):

“A man is a man for all that” means little out of its context, which is a poem by Robert Burns. Briefly, the poem refers to poor men, rich men, kings, lords, proud men, greedy men and others. All these people, despite their superficial differences in status and rank, are men. I suggest that “for all that” means something like “despite the differences”.